# Identifying matrix transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Say that you have a question like this;

[image]

How would you go about figuring out the transformations which have taken place? I tried to pick two points, like the centre and the right-most point on the circle, and mapped them onto the centre of the ellipse and the right-most point on the ellipse, but it did not work.

After working through this, defining by eye, the transformations which produced this ellipse produced the correct answer, but I was wondering if there were any other easier ways to complete this question in an exam situation?

Comment: What do you mean by “it didn’t work?” How do you know that your answer was wrong. If you show more of your work, it’s much more likely that someone will be able to tell you if and where you’re going wrong.

Comment: Hint: you need three point pairs to completely characterize an affine transformation.

Comment: @amd I would love to show my working, but the Stack Exchange app has trouble uploading images for some reason. It did not work as I found the transformation T, worked out T^(-1), and applied it to the original circle equation, but I did not get the resultant ellipse. Could you please elaborate on your three point method?

Comment: Take the time to type it in instead of uploading a picture of it. You’re asking people to spend their time to help you; it’s only fair that you take some of your own time to make it easier for them.

Comment: @amd I have no idea how to use MathJax... Can you please just tell me another way to approach this question?

Comment: Well, a big time-saver on exams is not to do more work than required. The question isn’t asking you for a sequence of transformations, but only for the final result. If you’re fluent with basic transformation and how to combine them, and can eyeball a set that work, that’s great, but often the quickest and simplest way is to examine what happens to the standard basis vectors. That’s the case here: the points of tangency of the circle with the coordinate axes are good surrogates for them.

Comment: As for the equation of the ellipse, you ought to be able to write that down without bothering with any of the preceding transformation stuff.

Comment: @amd The ellipse equation is easy to get just by looking at it, but could you please elaborate on the 'tangency' method you have talked about above? I am not sure I fully understand what you are talking about.